# XPath predicate combinations for multiple elements

Tags: xpath, nokogiri, predicate

Using ruby 1.9.3 and Nokogiri (latest):

Given (no, I did not come up with this):

```
<root>
<subelement>
    <key>
          <var name="id">50</var>
          <var name="secondaryid">0</var>
     </key>
</subelement>
<subelement>
   <key>
          <var name="id">50</var>
          <var name="secondaryid">1</var>
   </key>
</subelement>
</root>
```

Return the parent element (<key>) which has a var element with name property equal to "id" and a value equal to 50 AND a var element with name property equal to "secondaryid" and a value equal to 0.  Do not return the node with id=50 and secondaryid=1.

Obviously it's going to be built off something along the lines of:

@doc.xpath("//var[@name='id' and text()=50]")

but I can't figure out how to add another predicate that will match the name = "secondaryid" element too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested with Ruby, but this should do the trick.

```
//key[var[@name='id'] = '50'][var[@name='secondaryid'] = '0']
```

Comment: I was looking for secondaryid = 0, but other than that little typo, perfect.  In the interim, I came up with another solution that worked, but much more inelegant, and possibly has gotchas `//var[@name='id' and text()=50]/../var[@name='secondaryid' and text()=0]/..`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
subelement/key
  [var[@name="id" and . = "50"]]
  [var[@name="secondaryid" and . = "0"]]
```